# Centering the Pseudo-Element

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to center this triangle to the center of the `a` element using CSS, here is the CodePen:
http://codepen.io/DerekDev/pen/yyjqvd

As you can see, when you hover over a menu item, the triangle is not center, but is off to the right side.

```
.menu a {
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size:24px;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  padding-top:23px;
  padding-bottom:23px;
  transition:.5s;
}
.menu a:hover:after {
  opacity:1.0;
}
.menu a:after {
  transition:.5s;
  opacity:0.0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid #217aa4;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:75px;
}
.menu a:hover {
  background-color:#217aa4;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `pseudo-element` use `absolute` position, in this case you need to make relative the `a` parent:

```
.menu a {
  position:relative;
}
```

Then use a combination of `left` and `translate` to get the perfect center:

```
.menu a:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:100%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%)
}
```

#### [CodepenDemo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JovaZv)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.menu a:after`:

```
left: calc(50% - 37.5px);
```

And this to the `.menu a`:

```
position: relative;
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c9br43sv/

Comment: Keep in mind that IE won't like that `calc()`ulation, so best to use it only in `@media` width queries narrow enough that you're safe assuming you're on a phone (and therefor not in IE)